# How to insert a landscape page before endnotes page in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, landscape, endnote

I want to insert some landscape pages in my word document. I click in the first page that I want to make it landscape and then I select "Page Layout > Break > Next Page" but the endnotes page that is after that page (and must be) moves to the previous page of that page.
How can I insert landscape pages just before endnotes page in Word 2010?

---

#### Suggested rewrite:

<sup>(Translation into English)</sup>

I’m working with a Microsoft Word document that uses endnotes.  It is all one Microsoft Word “section”, in portrait orientation; let’s say it is three pages long.  I want to add page 4 in landscape mode, and then switch back to portrait for the rest of the document.  So I click at the bottom of page 3, select “Page Layout > Break > Next Page”, click in the newly created page 4, insert another section break, and then I can format section 2 (page 4) as landscape.  This works fine, but the endnotes stay behind on page 3.  I want to have the endnotes on the last page; how can I do this?

Comment: I don’t understand the question, and the lack of activity (after five hours!) suggests that other people may be having a problem with it, too.  Please **edit your question** and try to explain more clearly what you mean.

Comment: OK. done, sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the thing in the lower right corner of the “Footnotes” panel on the “References” tab:

[image]

This should bring up the “Footnote and Endnote” dialog box. 
Make sure “Endnotes” is selected, and then make sure that the “Location”
is set to “End of document” (rather than “End of section”):

[image]

Click on “Apply”.  Note: this answer is based on Microsoft Word 2007 (but apparently it works for Microsoft Word 2010 as well).

Answer (score 0):

Select the page you want to make landscape. Go to **Page Layout**, click on the little button in the corner of **Page Setup**, click on **Landscape** and set **Apply To** to **Selected sections**.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work, because making landscape applies to selected "section" not selected "page", and all of my doc is one section, and when I want to create a new section before endnotes page, endnotes pages that belongs to the previous section moves to the end of that section.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but still thought it was worth answering as I couldn't find a solution elsewhere online.

I had same issue, but I still wanted my end notes to display at the end of each section (switching to end of document was not my desired end product).

Solution to this is to suppress end notes before the landscape page, and then they will automatically move to next section.

Instructions:

- Click in a section.
- Go to Page Layout: Margins.
- Pull down to Custom margins.
- Click on Layout tab.
- Check suppress endnotes.
- Repeat for every section where end notes are displaying, and you don't want them to. They automatically move to the next section.